# How to set the language for all the envelopes and notifications created via SDK in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to be able to set the language for all the notifications and envelope that the users will receive

```
Signer signer = new Signer
                    {
                        Email = signerModel.EMail,
                        Name = signerModel.Name,
                        RecipientId = signerModel.OrderIndex.ToString(),
                        RoutingOrder = signerModel.OrderIndex.ToString(),
                        EmailNotification = new RecipientEmailNotification() { SupportedLanguage = "en" }
                    };
```

This is not solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

At this point you cannot do this in this way. The user can pick their language in their settings, but that would take precedent over what you set for the envelope.

Comment: Is there any other way or workaround that I can set to delimitate the envelopes and notifications language for all my users?